# Using Awesomium in orchard cms module

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, awesomium

I am trying to write an orchard module which will get some HTML pages from predefined urls (javascript executed) to extract some html from it. i ended up by Awesomium browser engine.as Awesomium intended to be run in a single thread , i have created a SingletonDependency and a thread in it which will continue running while the module is alive.thus far any thing is not a problem and the program works fine in local machine.but when i deploy the module on the server the Awesomium documentReady event never gets fired.i have tested the library (Awesomium) in a test ASP.NET mvc app and it works as expected.
following are some code snippet from what i have done so far :

```
public class DownloadService : IDownloadService
{
    private Thread downloaderThread;
    const int MillisecondsTimeout = 30000;
    private List<DownloadQueueItem> downloadQueue = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DownloadQueueItem>();

    private void DoDownloadTask()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (downloadQueue.Any())
            {
                var itemToDownload = downloadQueue.FirstOrDefault(qi => qi.IsCompleted == false);
                if (itemToDownload != null)
                {
                    var webPreferences = WebPreferences.Default;
                    using (var session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(webPreferences))
                    {
                        using (var view = WebCore.CreateWebView(800, 600, session))
                        {                                  
                            view.Source = new Uri(itemToDownload.Url, UriKind.Absolute);
                            bool finishedLoading = false;
                            bool isReady = false;

                            view.LoadingFrameComplete += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                if (e.IsMainFrame)
                                    finishedLoading = true;
                            };

                            view.DocumentReady += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                isReady = true;
                            };

                            int timeSpent = 0;
                            while (!finishedLoading || !isReady)
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(500);
                                WebCore.Update();
                                timeSpent += 500;
                                if (timeSpent > MillisecondsTimeout)
                                {
                                    isReady = true;
                                    finishedLoading = true;
                                    itemToDownload.Result = "";
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if (timeSpent < MillisecondsTimeout)
                            {
                                itemToDownload.Result = view.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML");                                        
                            }
                            itemToDownload.IsCompleted = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            downloadQueue = downloadQueue.Where(qi => !qi.IsProcessed).ToList();

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

The scenario : I am trying to setup an infinite loop to check for update within an specific interval and download some `HTML` pages and search for special tags in them with specific selectors (by means of CsQuery in my case) and then initialize `parts` and `fields` of `ContentItem` (with regard to Bindings rules i have defined earlier) with their contents.let me mention again "Everything works fine in local machine".
[Here](http://www.dotnettips.info/file/userfile?name=AwesomiumWebApplication_V1.0.zip) is a working example of Awesomium engine in an ASP.NET MVC application from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363648/can-i-use-awesomeium-within-a-web-application) SO question.My code is something like the example provided.in that example IHttpModule is used to do download task but in my case a class drived from ISingletonDependency.

**Update 2**

After hours of debugging i finally figure out what is the problem.problem is Awesomium.Core dll has dependencies which asp.net server copies them to following directory:

```
"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\8b7dd3d5\\5e9b4019\\assembly\\dl3\\788672a2\\001db261_934ccf01"
```

in orchard dependencies copied to Dependencies folder automatically but not any type of files (only dll(s) i think).in my scenario there is a file called `awesomium_process` which orchard cannot copy this file to dependencies folder.and this is the exact ptoblem.

**Update 3**

I Added these files manually and everything is working like a charm.but still i am after a solution to copy them programmatically.

Comment: Single thread components should never be used in any web application. You'll get unpredictable failures if you do. I don't know of a good .net headless browser that would work with JavaScript-generated markup. You might want to re-think your scenario. What is the scenario by the way?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy thanks for your response.before Awesomium i have tried out NHtmlUnit, it worked just as i expect but the problem was performance.it toke about one minute to get page and execute javascript.i will update question to describe the scenario.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy now i found the problem.i will add update2 to my question.who better than you to solve an orchard problem ;D!